# how to install python pgmagick on windows

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, installation, pgmagick

I m trying to install pgmagick library on windows. I m following the official page:
http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pgmagick/

From there i can notice that i need to install first easy_install,pip, boost and graphicsMagic.
In this page i found easy_install:
http://blog.troygrosfield.com/2010/12/18/installing-easy_install-and-pip-for-python/
In this page i can find pip and boost:
http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pgmagick

But i can't figure out how to install magick++. I went to website and download it but it installs just the software and when i try to install pgmagick like this:
 pip install pgmagick

there is an error that i need magick++:

```
F:\Python27\Scripts>easy_install -ZU pgmagick
Searching for pgmagick
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/pgmagick/
Reading http://bitbucket.org/hhatto/pgmagick
Best match: pgmagick 0.5.4
Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pgmagick/pgmagick-0.5.4.tar
.gz#md5=c10a454331ac1c359b39e50663fd28e4
Processing pgmagick-0.5.4.tar.gz
Running pgmagick-0.5.4\setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir f:\docume~1\alessa~1\imp
ost~1\temp\easy_install-xaypdo\pgmagick-0.5.4\egg-dist-tmp-qu7mji
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Python27\Scripts\easy_install-script.py", line 8, in <module>
    load_entry_point('setuptools==0.6c11', 'console_scripts', 'easy_install')()
  File "F:\Python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line
1712, in main
    with_ei_usage(lambda:
  File "F:\Python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line
1700, in with_ei_usage
    return f()
  File "F:\Python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line
1716, in <lambda>
    distclass=DistributionWithoutHelpCommands, **kw
  File "F:\Python27\lib\distutils\core.py", line 152, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "F:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "F:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "F:\Python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line
211, in run
    self.easy_install(spec, not self.no_deps)
  File "F:\Python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line
446, in easy_install
    return self.install_item(spec, dist.location, tmpdir, deps)
  File "F:\Python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line
476, in install_item
    dists = self.install_eggs(spec, download, tmpdir)
  File "F:\Python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line
655, in install_eggs
    return self.build_and_install(setup_script, setup_base)
  File "F:\Python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line
930, in build_and_install
    self.run_setup(setup_script, setup_base, args)
  File "F:\Python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line
919, in run_setup
    run_setup(setup_script, args)
  File "F:\Python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 62, in run_se
tup
    lambda: execfile(
  File "F:\Python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 105, in run
    return func()
  File "F:\Python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 64, in <lambd
a>
    {'__file__':setup_script, '__name__':'__main__'}
  File "setup.py", line 74, in <module>
Exception: Magick++ not found
```

thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend you use the precompiled binary packages from the [Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pgmagick) (as mentioned in the [pgmagick](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pgmagick/) web page), instead of trying to compile from source which will be quite a complicated process.